# Закрытое наследование: request for member 'eat' in 'b', which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. У меня есть следующий код а-ля `HelloWrold`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
    public :
        void eat ()const
        {
            cout << "inside eat" << endl;
        };
};

class B : private A
{
    public :
       using A::eat;
};

int main()
{

   B b();  // {1}
   B b;    // {2}
   b.eat();
   return 0;
}
```

Собственно вопрос: если закомментировать строку {1} и раскомментировать строку {2} то все компилируется. А если наоборот закомментировать строку {2} и раскомментировать строку {1} то выдается сообщение об ошибке "`request for member 'eat' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'B ()()`"

В чем же причина такого поведения компилятора? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому, что `B b();` это не определение переменной, а определение функции `b` без аргументов, которая возвращает `B`. Проверить это легко - добавьте в класс B конструктор по умолчанию, который выводит в лог/консоль.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
    public :
      B() {
         cout << "bbb" << endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
   B b();
   return 0;
}
```

В логе будет пустота.

Детали можно почитать в стандарте в пунктах 6.8 и 8.2

Comment: спасибо) Не настал еще для меня миг просветления в С++...я-то наивно думал, что B b - это объявление переменной без ее инициализации (вызова конструктора) а B b() - это объявление и вызов конструктора

Comment: @Andy_Reed: это известная проблема в синтаксисе C++. Обратите внимание, что если бы конструктор принимал _аргумент_, `B b(x)` было бы именно вызовом конструктора (если, конечно, `x` — не название типа). Кроме того, для конструктора без аргументов `new B` и `new B()` — не совсем одно и то же.